# SWI-Prolog rule assertion from passed List

Tags: prolog

I use swiprolog and have a knowlegdebase with some facts like:

```
det(the).
det(a).
adjective(quick).
adjective(brown).
noun(cat).
noun(fox).
prep(on).
prep(with).
verb(sat).
verb(ran).
```

and I have a rule

```
generate_grammar(GrammarList):- 
         new_rule(GrammarList).
```

This rule gets passed a list with an unknown number of elements e.g. `[det,noun,verb,prep]` and should generate a new rule for the passed "grammar". The new rule should generate a "sentence" with the given facts and the new grammar. I tested some things but I didn´t get it worked.

I think the desired rule looks something like:

```
new_rule(List) :- 
    Head=sentence(X),
    Body=[List] 
    dynamic(Head),
    assertz(Head :- Body).
```

I have no idea how to do this right. So how could this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen the univ operator yet? `X =.. [det, D]` unifies `X` with `det(D)`. Might be useful to you for this project.

Comment: Hey Daniel, yes I actually used this operator in this project but I have no idea how to deal with the list

Comment: Not sure you have to actually build the rules; this seems to do what you have asked for: `maplist(call, [det,adjective,noun,verb], Sentence).`

Comment: Thank you @DanielLyons !! That works perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it probably is possible to add rules to the store dynamically using `assertz/1` et. al. I have never really had to do it, because it's too easy to get Prolog to evaluate other data structures.

For your particular database, all your facts have arity 1, so we can just use `call/2` to evaluate them:

```
?- call(det, D).
D = the ;
D = a.
```

Leveraging this, you can solve the problem using `maplist/2` without any actual intermediate structures:

```
sentence(Grammar, Words) :- maplist(call, Grammar, Words).
```

Using it:

```
?- maplist(call, [det,adjective,noun,verb], Sentence).
Sentence = [the, quick, cat, sat] ;
Sentence = [the, quick, cat, ran] ;
Sentence = [the, quick, fox, sat] ;
Sentence = [the, quick, fox, ran] ;
Sentence = [the, brown, cat, sat] ;
Sentence = [the, brown, cat, ran] ;
Sentence = [the, brown, fox, sat] ;
Sentence = [the, brown, fox, ran] ;
Sentence = [a, quick, cat, sat] ;
Sentence = [a, quick, cat, ran] ;
Sentence = [a, quick, fox, sat] ;
Sentence = [a, quick, fox, ran] ;
Sentence = [a, brown, cat, sat] ;
Sentence = [a, brown, cat, ran] ;
Sentence = [a, brown, fox, sat] ;
Sentence = [a, brown, fox, ran].
```

Comment: In prolog this works pretty fine, but I also use python with pyswip for the queries. If I make a query with `result = list(prolog.query('sentence(X)'))`, 
my output is something like:  `[{'A': [Atom('396421'), Atom('397317'), Atom('393093')]}]`. For other queries without maplist this works fine. Did you have an idea whats I doing wrong?

Comment: @J4ck I have never used pyswip and don't know the first thing about what that problem is. It looks like you might have to do something to get the value of the atom separately.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually turn this into a true relation by adding facts for the known syntactic categories:

```
category(det).
category(adjective).
category(noun).
category(prep).
category(verb).
```

Then you can describe a relation between categories and words that belong to those categories:

```
cat_word(C,W) :-
   category(C),
   call(C,W).

?- cat_word(C,W).
C = det,
W = the ;
C = det,
W = a ;
C = adjective,
W = quick ;
C = adjective,
W = brown .
.
.
.
```

Finally, following the idea presented by @Daniel Lyons, you can apply maplist/3 to cat_word/2:

```
grammar_sentence(G,S) :-
   maplist(cat_word,G,S).
```

In the grammar to sentence direction this yields the same results as Daniels predicate sentence/2:

```
?- grammar_sentence([det,adjective,noun,verb],S).
S = [the, quick, cat, sat] ;
S = [the, quick, cat, ran] ;
S = [the, quick, fox, sat] ;
S = [the, quick, fox, ran] ;
S = [the, brown, cat, sat] ;
S = [the, brown, cat, ran] ;
S = [the, brown, fox, sat] ;
S = [the, brown, fox, ran] ;
S = [a, quick, cat, sat] ;
S = [a, quick, cat, ran] ;
S = [a, quick, fox, sat] ;
S = [a, quick, fox, ran] ;
S = [a, brown, cat, sat] ;
S = [a, brown, cat, ran] ;
S = [a, brown, fox, sat] ;
S = [a, brown, fox, ran].
```

But grammar_sentence/2 can also be used in the sentence to grammar direction:

```
?- grammar_sentence(G,[the,quick,cat,sat]).
G = [det, adjective, noun, verb] ;
false.

?- grammar_sentence(G,[the,cat,sat]).
G = [det, noun, verb] ;
false.
```

Comment: That is a significant improvement!